# how to find and use defined variables of less in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, less-css

basically i want to use the defined less variables in my custom theme.i have created a child theme of Luma .In child theme i have created a _theme.less file and by using the defined variables of less i changed the header panel background color by using

```
@header-panel__background-color: @color-black;
```

but i am confused where is the @header-panel__background-color is defined .i have searched also in lib folder but can't find any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check below file in vendor directory

> vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less

Here in this file you can see this **@header-panel__background-color**.

Here in this less file Magento defines color for "@header-panel__background-color" so whenever we want to use this color code we will not add **#4D926F** there, we can use below line in our .less file to use same color.

```
#header {
  color: @header-panel__background-color;
}
```

So in Header I get this color "#4D926F".

You can check this for your reference [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(stylesheet_language)).

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply,it will the change the header background color ,but my question is when i inspect header there is no class defined.how to guess header-panel class?

Comment: Answer updated. Please review and let me know if you need any help then

Comment: Let me know if it helps. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer .its helps a lot.

Comment: You're welcome Buddy :)